# How can I stop Excel from displaying numbers in scientific notation using XlsxWriter?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm exporting data to XLSX using pandas, which in turn is using `XlsxWriter`. I've experimented with the formatting options I've found (e.g. `float_format`, despite the fact that it seemed like the wrong answer based on the source), but I can't find anything that prevents Excel from interpreting numbers in scientific notation.

For example, if I write `0.000000000001`, the underlying cell value in Excel is `0.000000000001`, but the display value is `1E-12`. I know that I can write the number as a string, but I'd like the value to be numeric in Excel.

Comment: u need to change cell formating in excel do to fractions

Comment: I'm asking how to change the formatting using pandas/XlsxWriter itself, or is it impossible. From a conversation with a colleague of mine, my understanding is that libraries in other languages support this. Ideally, users should not see scientific notation at all, instead of making a manual change after they open the file.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot stop Excel from displaying an unformatted number in whatever format it thinks is suitable. The only way to guarantee the format is to specify a numerical format for the data.

Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this in XlsxWriter and or, as a result, in Pandas.

A feature such as this is on the [TODO list](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/111) however it probably won't be available for a while.

As a workaround I recommend getting a reference to the underlying workbook and worksheet and overwriting any cells that you wish to be formatted with the same data from the Pandas dataframe and a XlsxWriter format. I'll update later with an example of how to do that.

Disclaimer: I wrote XlsxWriter and the Pandas/XlsxWriter integration code. The issue here is really to do with XlsxWriter limitations and not Pandas.

Comment: Thanks! This is the confirmation I needed. I don't quite understand the workaround you propose, so I'll wait until you provide the example to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the length of number and then use code like the following:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('Num')

cell_format = wb.add_format({'num_format': '0.00000000000000'})
ws.write('A1', 0.000000000001, cell_format)

wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just format the number when you specify in the write() method. Eg:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('testme')
ws.write('A1', '%s' %123232323232323232435454546565)
wb.close()
```