# fixing improper ID formatting

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

**Background**: The following code works to export a `pandas` `df` as an `excel` file:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Excel_File.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

**Problem**:
My `ID` column in the `excel` file shows up like 
`8.96013E+17` instead of `896013350764773376`

I try to alter it in `excel` using `format` and `zipcode` but it still gives the wrong `ID` `896013350764773000`

**Question:** Using `excel` or `python` code, how do I keep my original `896013350764773376` `ID` format?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074255/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-displaying-numbers-in-scientific-notation-using-xlsxwr?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel uses IEEE754 doubles to represent numbers and they have 15 digits of precision. So you are not going to be able to represent an 18 digit id as a number in Excel. You will need to convert it to a string to maintain all the digits.